# Javascript mouse clicks not registering in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mouseevent

I'm creating a bit of code at the moment to play a top trumps style card game in javascript and have hit a snag with clicking the cards in Firefox.  My code word fine in all other browsers but firefox just doesn't register the click on the card where I'm clicking.

This is a bit of my code to show how I'm reading the mouse clicks and how they are being used. Hopefully it's just something silly I've missed.

EDIT : I maybe should have mentioned that the game is within a canvas as part of a html page

```
var mouseX = e.offsetX;
var mouseY = e.offsetY;

if(turn == 'Player')
{
    if(mouseX >= 110 && mouseX <= 325)
    {
        if(mouseY >= 265 && mouseY <= 285)
        {
        playerChoice = 'ppi';
        }
        if(mouseY >= 286 && mouseY <= 306)
        {
            playerChoice = 'hp';
        }
        if(mouseY >= 307 && mouseY <= 327)
        {
            playerChoice = 'aa';
        }
        if(mouseY >= 328 && mouseY <= 348)
        {
            playerChoice = 'ad';
        }
        if(mouseY >= 349 && mouseY <= 369)
        {
            playerChoice = 's';
        }
        if(mouseY >= 370 && mouseY <= 390)
        {
            playerChoice ='bs';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kevin said, there's no `offsetX` or `offsetY` to use. As an alternative to his suggestion, there's `element.getBoundingClientRect()`. Example:

```
var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();    
mouseY = e.clientY - rect.top;
mouseX = e.clientX - rect.left;
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/GideonPARANOID/7987806).

Answer (score 0):

The `MouseEvent` object in Firefox does not contain `offsetX` and `offsetY`.  Try using `layerX` and `layerY`.  This will make the script cross browser compatible.

```
var mouseX = (e.hasOwnProperty("offsetX") ? e.offsetX: e.layerX;
var mouseY = (e.hasOwnProperty("offsetY") ? e.offsetY: e.layerY;
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/W4hgR/